# How to cancel angularjs $timeout when user navigate away from the page

Tags: web-applications, angularjs, web, timeout

I use `$timeout` to routinely update the info on one of the page in my angularjs app. I'd like to cancel the `$timeout` when user navigate away from this page. Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution after digging around:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $timeout.cancel(timeout);
});
```

Or for the new component syntax in Angular 1.5:

```
this.$onDestroy = function() {
    if (timeout) {
        $timeout.cancel(timeout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For clarification, the `timeout` variable is the timer id, returned by the `$timeout(...)` call. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897608/cancel-a-angularjs-timeout-on-routechange?rq=1 for a related question.