# Using setTimeout() in Angular $rootScope event

Tags: javascript

I'm using an Angular plugin called ng-cart to add a shopping cart to my website.

The ng-cart plugin broadcasts an event when and item is added to the shopping cart.

I would like it to display the shopping cart summary then fade out using the setTimeout() function each time an item is added.

```
    $rootScope.$on('ngCart:itemAdded', function (event, data) {         
        if(!$('#cart-summary-container').is(":visible"))  {         
            $('#cart-summary-container').fadeIn('fast');
            clearTimeout(myVar);
            myVar = setTimeout(function() { $('#cart-summary-container').fadeOut('fast'); }, 2000); 
        }       
    });
```

The problem is I need to cancel the setTimeout() function if another item is added so that it displays for the 2 seconds.

I have tried to clearTimeout(myVar) before resetting the timeout.

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this I'm missing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: AngularJs? You should use the timeout service instead. Check here how to cancel https://stackoverflow.com/q/14897608/445600

Comment: I'm not sure how clearTimeout behaves if myVar has not been set before, but the standard says for clearTimeout, that the first parameter is required, so I would wrap that clearTimeout in an if-statement. Aside from that, I don't see any issue.

You didn't specify what's going wrong tho, so maybe there is something else.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that about clearTimout() so your saying check if myVar is initialized before calling setTimout(). If I remember correctly the problem was that when a second item was added the popup would fadeout earlier than it should because of the first call to setTimout().

Comment: `clearTimeout()` does nothing if the argument is not an existing timeout identifier, so it's safe to call it before initializing the variable.

Comment: This should basically work, but in which scope did you declare `myVar`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$rootScope.$on('ngCart:itemAdded', function (event, data) {

    $('#cart-summary-container').fadeIn('fast');

    if($rootScope.yourTimer) {
        $timeout.cancel($rootScope.yourTimer);      
    }

    $rootScope.yourTimer = $timeout(function() { $('#cart-summary-container').fadeOut('fast'); }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I did think it was the scope of the variable and have changed that to $rootScope along with starcorn suggestion of using the timeout service. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

a long time ago I solved it with the code below ;)

```
//usage  //->this=window
this.setTimeout(function(){//or event [click,]
  this.clearTimeout(this.setTimeout1);
}, 10);

this.setTimeout1 = this.setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(this);
}, 1000);

//usage
//this.clearTimeout(this.setTimeout1);
```